# How to have two GORM sessions to the same in-memory database?

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I am trying to test GORM code.  The code paths open a new GORM session.  The first session adds data to GORM, the second session uses it.  When testing, it seems that GORM will forget the first session's data when using the in-memory parameter, `:memory:`.  I even tried the `cache=shared` option with no success.

Here's an example test:

```
type testRecord struct{
    ID string
    Data string
}


func TestOpenGormTwice(t *testing.T){
    cxn:=":memory:?cache=shared"
    database, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", cxn)
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    err=database.CreateTable(&testRecord{}).Error
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    err=database.Create(testRecord{
        ID:   "1",
        Data: "abc",
    }).Error
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    tr:=testRecord{}
    err=database.First(&tr).Error
    assert.NoError(t, err)

    assert.True(t, database.HasTable(&testRecord{}))

    //Open :memory: again, hopefully it won't forget what was saved last time
    database2, err := gorm.Open("sqlite3", cxn)
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    assert.True(t, database2.HasTable(&testRecord{}))
}
```

The test fails at the last assert.True.  How can this code be changed to pass the last test?

I also tried `cxn:="memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared"`, it appeared to work, but in reality it is not going into an in-memory mode [as described in the Sqlite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#temp_db).

Comment: Does `cxn:="file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared"` as described at  [sqllite.org](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#temp_db) work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:  `cxn:="file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared"`

Thanks for the comment from @karmakaze.